# Word for during recent frame of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

> The court's ruling is claimed to be (...) because it has only counted specific actions to set up some (...) simple structure of justice that only encompasses the last hour neglecting the history of events.

(...) = ? = "has only lasted for a short amount of time prior to being mentioned"

Referring to current attitudes that have arisen in the general span of an hour or day or other fairly newly developed engagement. "Of the moment" "According to recent neoteric dispositions"

The structure is simple because it is founded on only one or two just-happened pieces of evidence.

Adjacent to "transient" "transitory" "ephemeral" but in reference to a newly grown/spoken structure of logic.

"recent" and "latest" seem too general and encompassing an indeterminate amount of time, whereas the word I'm looking for refers only to the nature of the just-referenced events, which is (...)

**Transient = lasting for a short amount of time**

**(...) = *has only lasted* for a short amount of time**

Comment: What's wrong with "recent" or "latest"?

Comment: "recent" and "latest" seem too general and encompassing an indeterminate amount of time or information, whereas the word I'm looking for refers to a now-determined period of new establishment. Now-determined because of counting specific actions sets up a structure of justice based solely on recent events. Or even counting favors to set up a simple structure of fairness would be creating a (...) modicum of equality.

Comment: Your sentence does not make much sense.... a now determined period of new establishment??

Comment: I got lost in reading a stream-of-consciousness post. You wanted a synonym for transient/fleeting/passing in the past?

Comment: Is the ruling no longer in effect, or time-limited? I'm not really sure what you're aiming at, but something like "short-lived" or "quickly-overruled"? Otherwise, I still don't see why "recent", "new", etc, don't work - if it's insufficiently precise then specify a time period!

Comment: Is the cited sentence a real sentence that you have found somewhere? Or your own concoction?   The "last hour" is  throwing me off --is that meant to be a crude sort of exaggeration or sarcasm?  Also, the phrase "is claimed to be" suggests perhaps you're looking for a term that is pejorative.